# Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

Error: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [curr_step] in table [risk_workflow]; found [varchar2 (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [number(19,0) (Types#BIGINT)]

Please let me know how can we solve this?

Column declaration in entity class "risk_workflow"

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "CURR_STEP")
private WorkflowTaskRoleMapping currentStep;
```

WorkflowTaskRoleMapping entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "WFTASK_ROLE_MPNG_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName ="WFTASK_ROLE_MPNG_SEQ",allocationSize = 1,name="WFTASK_ROLE_MPNG_SEQ")
private long id;

@Column(name = "TASK_NAME", length = 100)
private String taskName;

@Column(name = "ROLE", length = 25)
private String role;

@Column(name = "TASK_ORDR")
private int order;

@Column(name = "PROC_ID")
private long processId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of `WorkflowTaskRoleMapping` is a long and Hibernate maps it on the db with a column of type `number(19,0)`.

Hibernate expects the column `CURR_STEP` that maps the association to be the same type of the id in `WorkflowTaskRoleMapping` (`number(19,0)`).
The validation failed because the type of `CURR_STEP` in the db is `varchar2`.

It seems like you need to change the `curr_step` type on the db to `number(19,0)`.

Or, you can change the id type of `WorkflowTaskRoleMapping` to `String`;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it is not allowing me to modify column:
error: "column to be modified must be empty to change datatype"

and I can not delete the entries

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: What's the id column type of  `WorkflowTaskRoleMapping` table?